# Customize list in bibliography produced by biblatex

Tags: biblatex, horizontal-alignment

I'm using BibLaTeX for bibliography management with `bibstyle=gost-numeric` which is not that common, but the problem is the same with more common `bibstyle=numeric`. I want a list produced with `\printbibliography` to have following property: text of each list entry should appear with the specific (fixed) horizontal shift. I need this to align it with bibliography title.

At the current point it fails to aligh a little bit, as you can see here:

[image]

(I'm using custom `parindent`). Any ideas how to achieve this?

The MWE is as follows

```
\documentclass [fontsize=14pt, paper=a4, pagesize, DIV=calc] {scrartcl}

\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}

\usepackage{paratype}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  hyperref=auto,
  language=auto,
  citestyle=numeric,
  bibstyle=numeric,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\newlength\MyIndent
\setlength\MyIndent{1.25cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{\MyIndent}
\addtokomafont{sectioning}{\hspace{\MyIndent}}

\begin{document}

\addsec{Заключение}
We hope you find write\LaTeX\ useful, and please let us know if you have any feedback using the help menu above.

Помните, что на все пункты списка литературы должны быть ссылки. \LaTeX\ просто не добавит информацию об издании из bib-файла, если на это издание нет ссылки в тексте.

Для дальнейшего изучения \LaTeX\ рекомендуем книгу Львовского~\autocite{Lvo2003}.%~\autocite{BrPi2005}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

biblio.bib:

```
@MVBOOK{Lvo2003,
  author = {Львовский, Сергей Михайлович},
  title = {Набор и вёрстка в системе \LaTeX},
  year = {2006},
  language = {russian},
  publisher = {МЦНМО},
  location = {М.},
  hyphenation = {russian},
  url = {http://www.mccme.ru/free-books/llang/newllang.pdf}
}
```

Comment: `\RedeclareSectionCommand[indent={1.25cm}]{section}` Doesn't solve the problem though.

Comment: @Johannes_B great facility, didn't know about it, because I'm using a version of KOMA from my distr's (Ubuntu) repo, which is quite outdated. Though I'm working on a project which will be used by students who better stick to default packages from repos.

Comment: Doesn't my answer work for you?

Comment: @karlkoeller sorry, I've just came back home from my work. I'll write you back as I check it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to redefine the `bibliography` environment to achieve what you want.

So, add the following lines in your preamble

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
    \printfield{prefixnumber}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\dimexpr1.25cm-\labelwidth\relax}% <----- default is \biblabelsep
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
```

It works both with the `numeric` bibstyle and with the `gost-numeric` one, since both have the same original definition.

MWE (note that `babel` has to be loaded *after*  `fontenc`)

```
\documentclass [fontsize=14pt, paper=a4, pagesize, DIV=calc] {scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\usepackage{paratype}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  hyperref=auto,
  language=auto,
  citestyle=numeric,
  bibstyle=numeric,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\newlength\MyIndent
\setlength\MyIndent{1.25cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{\MyIndent}
\addtokomafont{sectioning}{\hspace{\MyIndent}}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
    \printfield{prefixnumber}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\dimexpr1.25cm-\labelwidth\relax}% <----- default is \biblabelsep
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\begin{document}

\addsec{Заключение}
We hope you find write\LaTeX\ useful, and please let us know if you have any feedback using the help menu above.

Помните, что на все пункты списка литературы должны быть ссылки. \LaTeX\ просто не добавит информацию об издании из bib-файла, если на это издание нет ссылки в тексте.

Для дальнейшего изучения \LaTeX\ рекомендуем книгу Львовского~\autocite{Lvo2003}.%~\autocite{BrPi2005}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: @ArtemPelenitsyn you're welcome.